# Is Local Fringing Entangled with Remote Measurement Given Interferometric Basis Discrimination?

Tags: special-relativity, optics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, polarization

[image: Young's-type setup, rev 9 Aug 2021][image: Present setup as an open limit of the Hardy Paradox setup]
For my own research and for the consideration of others, I am posing this puzzle.  Thank you for your thoughtful reply.

8/5/2021: [![Improved jargon -- I do not mean to give the impression that I am commenting on the observer problem.  Added a reference.  I am calling it a conjecture.][3]][3]

8/7/2021, Thank you to P.G.L. Porta Mana for making me think: the present topology is an open limit of the Hardy Paradox setup (drawing added) and vice versa.
8/1/2021, 1:20 PDT: Thank you, Mr. Alsept.  I have built the local optics.  So, I am saying that their operation is a given for definite input: For the local observer, H or V input produces a single phase of fringes, and D or AD input produces no fringes (ideally).  I note that the ordinary Young's (the secondary interferometer) has no effect on the polarization (here, the mixer makes the polarization definite D, but sometimes I remove the mixer).  These results are from a polarized laser.  Now, imagine spinning the polarized laser about its optical axis.  Sometimes the laser will be one of H, V, D, or AD, but usually it will be in a linear combination of H and V (both non-zero), or D and AD (both non-zero).  This situation produces exactly what you suggest, if I understand you correctly: observed 50% fringe visibility.  However, if the source is indefinite (I have not done this experiment), then entanglement experimenters say, if we can believe them, that the polarization is indefinite until measured (moreover, either remotely or locally measured).  Note that the local optics do not measure the polarization state, but only measure the polarization basis (whether the light is definitely a member of the H-V group, or the D-AD group).  How does the light decide which pattern to form?  Say that I place the remote measurer: now the light is definitely either H or V and the entangled beam must also be definitely H or V.  Therefore, I should have 100% fringe visibility for that case.  Now, I would be surprised if an indefinite source could produce 100% fringe visibility, if the remote measurer were removed.

Comment: Could you be more specific with your question or rephrase? From what I see in your illustrations Both outcomes can be explained with photon Particles impacting the detection screen.

Comment: All of the fringe patterns can be derived from the accumulation of individual photon impacts and has nothing to do with observation.

Comment: Thank you for you help and interest.  I have edited my question doing my best to be clear.  (BTW, thank you for Single Edge Certainty -- it makes me think and I find some intriguing concepts therein.)

Comment: I would also like to thank you, Mr. Alsept, for being the first to respond to my question.

Comment: I can respond to your question later when I get home

Comment: I have reviewed your illustration again and I’m still not sure I follow you. When you have definite vertical or definite horizontal polarized light entering the experiment then as you say only one polarizer will allow light to pass through. With only one source how do you get the interference pattern. Unless you’re talking about a single slit interference pattern. Sorry if I’m not following you but maybe I’m looking at your illustration wrong.

Comment: No problem.  My illustration may not be the best.  After the first (polarized) interferometer and the mixer, the next square is both an observation screen and an ordinary interferometer (kind of shown inset).  As long as the first interferometer is not fringing (is getting H or V input), then the second interferometer is evenly illuminated with a coherent wavefront.  Thus the second interferometer must produce fringes on the final observation screen.  Does that help?

Comment: Dear Mr. Alsept, I have done my best to clarify my old illustration with a new one (I don't see now how to delete the old one).  I have updated both the cartoons and some text.  If any sentence or drawing appears unclear or wrong, please don't hesitate say so.  I do not advocate what light is, but merely what light does in this situation.  I also don't identify with my ideas.  I am excited to learn what would happen non-locally.  Cheers.

Comment: Isn't the setup similar in principle to [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9501016) or [this](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.19.473)?

Comment: Correct me, if I am wrong: In principle, no because neither of those have series interferometers.

Comment: The fundamental problem with the primary stage alone is that D and AD are indistinguishable in practice, but not in principle.  The secondary stage makes it impossible in principle to make D and AD indistinguishable any longer without harming the overall distinguishability between the D-AD and H-V groups.  The secondary stage does so because at the slit spacing = (1/2)*(fringe period) condition, it inverts the existence of primary fringes.  My first blush is that a closer kinship is found with [Hardy's Paradox](http://quantum.phys.cmu.edu/CQT/chaps/cqt25.pdf) `

Comment: P.G.L. Porta Mana, I thank you for asking the question.  Present and Hardy topologies seem to be open limits of one another -- drawing added for Mach-Zehnder layout.